# Does IndexedDB support SQL-like transactions?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am trying to understand IndexedDB using the docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB).

I'm still not clear if it supports SQL-like transactions with rollbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

> IndexedDB is built on a transactional database model. Everything you
>   do in IndexedDB always happens in the context of a transaction. The
>   IndexedDB API provides lots of objects that represent indexes, tables,
>   cursors, and so on, but each of these is tied to a particular
>   transaction. Thus, you cannot execute commands or open cursors outside
>   of a transaction.

Further information there.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB